I want to remesh reduce a mesh using vertex colors based on curvature to determin poly density in areas of detail
I am stuck and need a smart friend!
I have a shape (.obj, vert=36,000, Face= 72,000), to which I have applied vertex colors using "Colorize Curvature (APPS)" with "Mean Curvature" as the Compute curvature method.
Now I want to use these curvature based vertex colors to to remesh/reduce the polygon densities of my object. The goal is to drive higher polygon density in areas of high curvature, and lower polygon densities in ares of less curvature.
I have tried Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation to no sucess.
How do you do this kind of processing on a geometry?
Thank you,
Andrew

